# Add Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data reference to a .NET 4 project

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, reference, enterprise-library

I'm trying to add Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data (v5.0.414.0) to a project that's targeting .NET 4. (using VS2010)

When I go to the "Add Reference" screen it shows up in Recent References as I've used it before. When I try to add it however, it tells me that it's incompatible with .NET 4:

---

**Incompatible reference**

"Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" is incompatible with .NET Framework 4

In order to add it you should to change the project's target to a compatible framework first.

---

When I change to a lower .NET version as the target for my project, none of the Microsoft.Practices assemblies show up at all.

The Microsoft download page for Enterprise Library v5 shows .NET 4 as a system requirement.

NOTE: I did install .NET 4.5 previously and then removed it (and also .NET 4) and then reinstalled .NET 4 - shouldn't be the issue here I hope.

How can I get my .NET 4 project to work with Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data?

UPDATE: when I include the reference to the .csproj file manually, it works. It's just Visual Studio that's being silly somehow.

Comment: Strange one...seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407461/vs2010-incompatible-reference-when-trying-to-add-reference